# Trying to Install OpenJDK Package 'openjdk-7-jre' has no installation candidate

Tags: java

I have just Updated to the new Ubuntu 16.04. This is a fresh installation of this OS. Trying to install Openjdk 7 but I got this error.

> Package 'openjdk-7-jre' has no installation candidate

how do I fix it?

Comment: Install 8 or 9 which has instalation canidates

Answer (score 4):

if you really want to install JDK7, add these in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file,

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

by issuing a following command,

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then run,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

run `apt-cache search openjdk-7-jre` to verify.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html)
2. Download the rpm
3. alien it

`alien jdk-7u80-linux-x64.rpm`

4. install it

`dpkg -i jdk_1.7.080-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: He asks for `OpenJDK` but you direct to `OracleJDK`.